# How to submit article in reddit for the app showdown?

Tags: application-development

Why i can't submit an article in reddit?
Isn't it approved or what?

i see it in my profile, but i don't see it in new articles...

Comment: The only mention of Reddit on http://developer.ubuntu.com/showdown/ is if you're looking for ideas for an app.  You shouldn't need to post to Reddit in order to participate in the contest.  Perhaps you could expand on your question?

Comment: Ask Reddit Support...

Comment: Posting on Reddit doesn't guarantee you will be mentioned in OMG Ubuntu articles. They only highlight great apps. Good luck for your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes i know there is no reason to submit it in reddit but for example omgubuntu said that at 1st week these applications have been submitted, ( based on reddit ). Anywho i will see what i can do..